# Аналог getmicrotime в perl?

Tags: php, perl

В `php` есть такая функция как microtime. Также его доп. реализация как getmicrotime();
В `perl` я нашёл только times, и то он всегда выдаёт 4 нуля.

```
function getmicrotime() 
{ 
   list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime()); 
   return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec); 
}
```

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes

Comment: @nörbörnën поделитесь кусочком кода плиз))

Comment: не понимаю как сделать кусочек кода оторванный от контекста, скорее всего тебе подойдёт `Time::HiRes::time`

Answer (score 1):

> **gettimeofday()**
>
> В контексте массива возвращает двухэлементный массив с
>   секундами и микросекундами с начала эпохи. В скалярном контексте
>   возвращает секунды (с плавающей точкой) как Time::HiRes::time()
>
> **tv_interval ( $ref_to_gettimeofday [, $ref_to_later_gettimeofday] )**
>
> Возвращает секунды секунды (с плавающей точкой) между двумя значениями, которые должны были быть возвращены gettimeofday (). Если
>   второй аргумент опущен, используется текущее время. [документация](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes)

```
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday tv_interval);

my $startTime = [ gettimeofday ];

# some actions

my $endTime = [ gettimeofday ];
my $elapsed = tv_interval($startTime,$endTime);

print "TIME: $elapsed\n";
```